# How to pass parameters from static html page to Lambda code written in java?

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I wish to pass my parameters of the form from Static page which I have been hosting on AWS S3 to AWS Lambda function in java which I am storing in RDS.
I am attaching my Lambda code and HTML code along with my API gateway post method screenshot.

```
[package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.amazonaws.Request;
import com.amazonaws.RequestConfig;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Request, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Request request, Context context) {

        String name="a";
        String Email="b";
        String phoneNo="1";
        String interest="a";
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXX");
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        s.executeUpdate("Insert into Contact_us (name,email,phone_no,interest) values('"+name+"','"+Email+"','"+phoneNo+"','"+interest+"')");
        s.close();
        con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        // TODO: implement your handler
        return "Hello from Lambda!";
    }

}][1]
```

```
<h1>Welcome to SoftVan ltd.</h1>
<form method=post action="API Trigger Link">
    Name<input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
    Email Id<input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
    Phone Number<input type="number" name="phoneno"><br><br>
    Interest<input type="text" name="interest"><br><br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Post Method API Gateway created to trigger Lambda Function[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYg55.jpg)